# How to assign security groups to web service operations for Human resource objects

Tags: api, web-services, soap, soapui, workday-api

I'm getting following error on few of the **web service operations** for **Human Resources** in **Workday**, for example these objects:

Error:
`The task submitted is not authorized` 
Complete error:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server.processingError</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Processing error occurred. The task submitted is not authorized.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <wd:Processing_Fault>
               <wd:Detail_Message>The task submitted is not authorized.</wd:Detail_Message>
            </wd:Processing_Fault>
         </detail>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Operations:
`Get_Academic_Units`
`similar related Academic operations`, and `Get_Change_Government_IDs`

It's because my user (admin), which I'm using to authenticate the API doesn't have access. Is there any proper guide or link that can help me setup all the web service operations for human resource for some particular user-assigned security group ?

I noticed that a security group named `Implementers` is assigned as `Secuirty Group Needed` for these web services where I'm getting this error, but I'm unable to add any user in that secuirty group, unlike others.

I'm new with workday and workday webservices, so any lead on this will really help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new integration security group and give Get Permission on the Domain Security Policy.

- For `Get_Academic_Units`  Domain security policy is `Set Up: Academic Units`
- For `Get_Change_Government_IDs`  Domain security policy is `Person Data: ID Information`